# Maven multi module dependency sharing

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have a maven multi module project with A as a parent project. B and C are the modules. How can I share some dependencies between B and C if I don't want B and C to inherit from A? ( so I can't put those dependencies in A from B and C to inherit them)

If I have this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupCommon</groupId>
        <artifactId>IdCommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I want this dependency to be used by every module but I don't to put it in every pom.xml. So basically, how can I share this dependency between module B and C without putting this dependency in project A and making B and C inherit from A?

Comment: [Importing Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple shared dependencies one option you have is to define a separate dependencies POM where you define all the shared dependencies (in the `<dependencies>` section, **not** the `<dependencyManagement>` section) and then define this POM as a dependency in your modules. By defining this shared-dependencies pom as a normal dependency all of its dependencies are include as transitive dependencies your modules.

You obviously would still have to define the a dependency to this pom in each of the module poms, but now it is one dependency instead of multiple.

So for example:

**dependencies pom**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>shared-dependencies-group</groupId>
<artifactId>shared-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Shared Dependencies</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupCommon</groupId>
        <artifactId>IdCommon1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupCommon</groupId>
        <artifactId>IdCommon2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- more dependencies -->
</dependencies>
```

**Module B pom**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>groupModules<groupId>
<artifactId>module-b</artifactId>
<name>Module B</name>
<dependencies>
    <!-- single dependency to the shared-dependencies pom instead of multiple dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>shared-dependencies-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The same would obviously be done in Module C's pom.